# All the facebook uid on my application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application associated with Facebook. 
When I say associated, I mean that the users gave me the permissions on the email and I store their uid in my database. 
What I want to do now, is to show them all their facebook friends that are in my application too. Moreover, if an user is visiting a profile of a friend of a friend's Facebook (second level) I would like to notify this in my application. 
In order to do this, I need to be able to retrieve all the friends' uid of my users.  **Does exist a GraphAPI function that gives me all the Friend uid connected to my app?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You can get it with the REST API [Facebook 'Friends.getAppUsers' using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2785093/305633)

You can only get the friends of a user who has given you permission to gather their friends. For example if you are logged in and go here, you should see all of your friends.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?your|tokens|here**
```

If you try to look up the friends of another user though you get an error message

```
"Can't lookup all friends of 555555. Can only lookup for the logged in user (515151), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"
```

See the [User object developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) docs.

**If you click on the links in here while logged into facebook it will automatically add in your appropriate tokens.

Comment: I know it. But what if I have the permissions about all the users in my platform? In such case it's completely legal to show all the friends that are in my app too, I can even rebuilt a graph of the users basing on the friend's list I gather by their permissions. So I repeat my question: In this case (where I have all the permissions) Does exists a GraphAPI function that gives me 
all the Friend uid connected to my app?

Comment: It looks like you can only get it with the old REST API http://stackoverflow.com/q/2785093/305633