# Facebook Graph API: Get date of joinin

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, installation, facebook-friends

Follow up to this question for [Facebook Friends.getAppUsers using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960272/22039) that pulls friends using app by
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=installed`

is it possible to get **date of joining** also with the id’s?

Comment: Just a comment, `me/friends?fields=installed`  This is interesting.  The installed field is not documented.  I wonder how many other fields are not documented on Graph API objects.

Comment: @DMCS it's not documented on `user` object documentation but somehow was noted on deprecation note for [`users.isAppUser`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.isAppUser/) of REST API.

Comment: Yeah, I know!  I wish there was a place we can look to find the other "hidden" (aka undocumented) properties there are on the Graph API that are only gettable with the fields= query string.

Comment: yup, just like how the [`backdated_time`](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8576541/upload-photos-for-past-date) field shocked me two days ago!!

Comment: Would you look at that :P  All the [big names](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) of [FSO](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/) in one place :)

Comment: @Lix, I would rather link to this [stat](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/topusers) (where I'm still ahead of DMCS!) ;-)

Comment: @ifaour - I really can't stand looking at FB questions anymore :P Dunno if you are on meta at all - but we are trying to change some things that might help let us keep our sanity with all the Facebook madness :P Check it out- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/stack-overflow-and-facebook-policy-matters-on-topic/126117#126117

Comment: @Lix, Yes I'm aware of the controversy that is happening on Meta. I also upvoted, favorite and commented on OffBySome [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership). Now let's keep this conversation relevant to the question ;). I would love to see Igy answering this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Currently it is not possible to get date of joining of user to app.

But you can do one thing whenever any fb user registers/ connects with facebook application, store current date/time with his facebook id in your system. And when you want display date of joining then map friends id with your database table.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't do this :( Even trying to get all their news feed and choosing the first or most backdated one won't work *anymore*. A very funny and probably irrelevant attempt could be by searching the user's inbox for a "welcome to facebook" message.

Also, if you could tell us why you need this information, you might be able to get suitable alternatives.

Comment: I would like this too because I want to use Facebook to help verify a person is real.  I.e. if they've had a facebook account for over a year with over 20 friend connections it's unlikely to be a bot as FB would probably have deactivated it.  It's far from full proof but is certainly better than asking them to send a birth certificate in

Comment: :) yes, I definitely agree though I'm not sure the OP intends to do that.