# How to notify app that user has changed in facebook app/ Safari IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

Using Facebook SDK 3.5.1 in my app, my requirement is that i have logged in the app via facebook with one user (say user A) and now if i login with other user (say user B) in mobile safari/facebook app (which one is available), in this case can my app get notified that another user logged in other than one who was logged in app.

Any references or ideas?

Thanks in advance

Note : I know that this Question was asked before but no answer is there :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option for this in the Facebook API. At least I couldn't find it.
[Facebook SDK for iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/)

What you can do, however, is simply check every minute or so who is available.
You can save this data in an array and then compare it a minute later with the new data.

Here is how you can fetch a list of your connected friends:
[iOS Facebook SDK - get list of Friends connected with App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457796/ios-facebook-sdk-get-list-of-friends-connected-with-app)

Comment: Thanks but i am able to get the presence of changed fb User in mine app when the user is changed through "SETTINGs" in I-phone device... :)

but looking forward to get get changed fb user (when Changed through fb app )