# Retrieve facebook friend who use my app and display them in a ListView

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to development with Facebook SDK. What I wanna do is pretty simple : I want to get all of the user's friends who are using my app, and display them in a ListView. I haven't found the answer in the official documentation.

Currently, this is what I'm doing :

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
              if (session.isOpened()) {
                  Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                        if(response.getError() == null) {
                            ...

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connectivity error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                  });
              }
            }
          });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785093/facebook-friends-getappusers-using-graph-api)?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with SDK 3.0 and this question was asked in 2010 :/